# How to upload the files from iPhone to server using mono-touch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Im going to develop the iPhone application for backup the files. So I need to upload the images or files like excel, text files from iPhone to server.

For example,

**choose the files  --> press upload button --> upload to server**

I want to design like upload widget. Im using MonoTouch for developing iPhone application. Is there any to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be researching how to do this in C# in general.  It should be the same as using MonoTouch.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) is an example link.  Of course, it all depends on what server you are wanting to upload the file to.  You don't mention what protocol you want to use, if it's Linux or Windows, if you have any control of the server, etc.